# How can I connect AirpodsPro with Ubuntu Linux 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, configuration, headphones, settings, headset

I need to connect my airpodsPro to Ubuntu for work and I can't seem to grasp the way through. I've tried with bredr, le, and dual options on the Bluetooth main conf.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello. There is no such version of Ubuntu as 20.05 Nor can an email be included in the question. What actual commands have you tried not just the name of the command the full command.

Comment: i tried: 
1) sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
2) changed ControllerMode = dual, bredr or le (one at a time);
3) sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart

Comment: If this is an answer choose the option at the bottom of the question to answer your own question and put it there. Not as a comment.

Comment: @David thanks men. Just did. Also, do you have any idea how to do what i asked for regarding enabling airpods as a headset?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: install blueman app on ubuntu Store. –
Still a problem to enable it as a full headset (airpods microphone). Please let me know if someone solves this issue.